# how to remove rows that are related to same values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

how do I turn this:

```
|  ID  | LETTER 
----------------     
|  1   |    A      
|  2   |    B            
|  3   |    B       
|  4   |    C       
|  5   |    D       
|  6   |    D      
|  7   |    F       
|  8   |    A
```

On this:

```
|  ID  | LETTER 
----------------            
|  4   |    C                  
|  7   |    F
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I fixed now, basically what I want to do is remove all the rows that has a repeated letter, in this case the ROW where the column ID  is : 1,2,3,5,6,8 got removed because they had a repeated letter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL 5.6,
If the table name is ***t_name***,
Then ***simplest query*** *to remove rows that are related to same values:*
*

> SELECT * FROM t_name
> Group by LETTER having count(LETTER)=1;

- 

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, one possible way is -

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t_system_log;

SELECT
    t_table.*
FROM
    t_table,
    (
    SELECT
        letter
    FROM
        t_table
    GROUP BY
        letter
    HAVING
        count(letter) = 1) AS t_unique
WHERE
    t_table.letter = t_unique.letter
;
```

[My Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=932a0393a9be604500e5c56fe16181ee)